# How to add a second UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, ios5

[image]I'm creating a project using UIPageViewController for the page turning effect. I'm using storyboard, which I think is great, to setup the UIPageViewController. How do I add a second UIPageViewController and hook it up? I have posted some screenshots to show what I've done so far.

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to create this second one? You'll need another view to put it in. If you have a Tab Controller, you can put one page view controller in another tab, or have a modal view appera and display the other page view controller. I don't think you can put an PageViewController inside another...

Comment: What I want to do is to insert multiple pages. How do I insert different views so it looks and reads like a book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is to implement the page view controller data source delegates:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

These two functions return the next and previous view controllers when they are requested from the page view controller.

If you make a new "Page-Based Application" project, you can follow how this done in the ModelController which is the data source for the example pageViewController.

Comment: So the key to adding pages is to use UIVewControllers in the data source?

Comment: Yes.  You're essentially sending instances of the custom view controller to the UIPageViewController to display.  In the case of the "Page-Based Application" xcode project template, the modelController is the data source for the pageViewController, and it provides instances of the dataViewController with different data.  Since, the function returns a UIViewController* you can use any instance of that class.