# iBooks like animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ibooks

I am trying to build a webshop for an iPad. Now I want to browse through the products like in ibooks. I looked it up on the internet, but they are all working with images, pdf, pages.

That's not what I want. I want to browse between xib files. If anyone has any ideas of good tutorials for it, let me know!

Answer (score 4):

[UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) gives you a page flip animation (like iBooks) between view controllers. I don't have a tutorial link for it, though, and I've not used it myself.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Just a tiny addendum: it is iOS5 and above only.

Comment: The best example is the sample application provided by apple when you make a new page based project.  I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171654/how-to-add-a-second-uipageviewcontroller/8215619#8215619).